# Python: Break out of while loop after time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, gpio

I am python programming a RPi.  I am using 'wait for edge' to count a Hall Sensor output for the RPM of a flywheel with two magnets attached.  The rpm routine is as follows:

```
# Imports
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Set GPIO Mode as BCM
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17 , GPIO.IN)         # Hall sensor attached to GPIO 17

def rpm():
    pulse = 0                    # Reset pulse counter
    endTime = time.time()+1      # Calculate end time in 1 second
    while time.time() < endTime: # Loop while time is less than end time
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.FALLING) # Wait for a falling edge
        pulse += 1               # Increment pulse
    pulse = str((pulse*60)/2)    # Calculate for pulse per minute
    return pulse                 # Return the 'RPM'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("You ran this module directly (and did not import it.")
    input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

The code works fine when the wheel is spinning and edge is triggered.  The issue is when the wheel stops and the edge is not triggered, the while loop never checks the exit clause and the programme stalls.  How can I guarantee to break out by the endTime even when pulse = 0? Thanks.

Comment: You will have to use threads if the `wait_for_edge` never returns or stalls out. See if it has a timeout parameter, if not, look at the threading.

Ultimately, you would create a thread and then check on it in intervals, until your desired timeout, and then cancel the thread if it exceeds your timeout window.

https://pymotw.com/2/threading/

Comment: I think this is where I need to head.  There is an alternative function: 'GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)' which actions the routien at my_callback whenever it is actioned.  I guess that could contain the increment function?

Comment: Nah see the answer. It has a timeout parameter. Check @natecat's answer (Thanks).

Answer (score 3):

[use the `timeout` parameter](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) so it will only wait for so long. For example, this code would only wait for 1 second before breaking out of the loop.

```
GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.FALLING, timeout = 1000)
```

You could also use `(endTime-time.time())*1000` as your timeout to make it wait until endTime to break out

Comment: Great, works fine. I now need to avoid it returning 1, instead of the correct 0, as following the timeout it still increments `pulse`.

Comment: If you looked at my link, they actually show an example of how to test if a timeout happened or an edge was detected.